# PhpStorm cannot debug remotely

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I can successfully validate debugger via `Run -> Web Server Debug Validation`.

You can see the snapshot below:

[image: PhpStorm debugger validate]

But after I create a Web Application in run/debug configure and click on debug button, what I got is only the message "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '18779' (random number)" in debug console.

Here is the setting in run configuration

[image: PhpStorm run configuration]

BTW: deploy server and server are not the same thing, which makes me confusing. And I can also debug locally.

Comment: Enable xdebug.remote_log in php.ini (it's better to create the file and set full permissions manually). Restart Apache and try to start a debug session again. Are there any messages written to the xdebug.log?

Comment: did you tried with Xdebug helper extension for chrome ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @EugeneMorozov. Here is the the xdebug setting in php.ini :
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="zhonggua.top"
xdebug.idekey = "phpstorm"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
One separate setting in other ini file under conf.d:
zend_extension=xdebug.so
Restart php5-fpm and nginx, but no luck!
I can find cache file created under /tmp/xdebug after debug session begins but no bp paused in PhpStorm.
Some lines of cache file:

Comment: @EugeneMorozov  here are some lines of log file, which is not generated everytime:vi cachegrind.out.9456 

version: 1
creator: xdebug 2.2.3
cmd: /home/gonglong/zg/php/etcp2/test.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time

fl=php:internal
fn=php::dirname
9 7

fl=php:internal
fn=php::dirname
2 0

fl=/home/gonglong/zg/php/etcp2/base/consts.php
fn=include_once::/home/gonglong/zg/php/etcp2/base/consts.php
1 16

fl=php:internal
fn=php::dirname
3 0

Comment: Is this Xdebug log? Doesn't look like that. Please consider contacting PhpStorm support, it's really difficult to troubleshoot that within the SO comments section.